# Export datagridview with multiline rows in .CSV

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to export some values and text from a datagridview to a .csv file.
everything works just fine if the rows in the dgv are single line, once I insert some multiline text the .cvs format looks something like this:

```
ID;RW;Name;Description;Def;Unit;Min;Max
test
machine 1;yes;boiler;2,2;no;mq;-;-
test 
machine 2;no;vent;66,9;no;fq;-;-
```

so the cells that have multiline text go on another line, how do I wrap that text with commas so excel can recognize them correctly?
like this:

```
ID;RW;Name;Description;Def;Unit;Min;Max
"test
machine 1";yes;boiler;2,2;no;mq;-;-
"test 
machine 2";no;vent;66,9;no;fq;-;-
```

Below is the code so far I wrote to do the first part.

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog

    sfd.FileName = "export-cvs"
    sfd.Filter = "CSV File|*.csv"

    If sfd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(sfd.FileName)

            'write the datagridview column into the first line of cvs file
            Dim dgvColumnsNames As List(Of String) = DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).ToList().Select(Function(c) c.HeaderText).ToList

            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(";", dgvColumnsNames))

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim rowData As New List(Of String)
                For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                    rowData.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells(column.Name).Value))
                Next
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(";", rowData))
            Next

            'open file after being written
            Process.Start(sfd.FileName)

        End Using

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just wrap every text value in double quotes. That it, that's all. It won't have any effect on values that don't contain field or record delimiters but will ensure that any that do will be treated as a single value. Any double quotes in the text should be escaped with another double quote.

Comment: yeah exactly, it just come up to my mind after posting this, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

My first solution was to use this, but I think I will wrap every text value in double quotes.

```
     If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(column.Name).Value).Contains(vbNewLine) Then
           Debug.WriteLine("NEWLINE")
           rowData.Add(ControlChars.Quote + Convert.ToString(row.Cells(column.Name).Value) + ControlChars.Quote)
     Else
           rowData.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells(column.Name).Value))
     End If
```